# Connect Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop to LDAP Server

Tags: 16.04, authentication, nfs, ldap, smb

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktopand read and tested a lot of documentation about configuring an LDAP client on Ubuntu but can't get it to work.

Is someone can share his experience and give me some good and working documentation?

My goal:

- Centralize authentication via LDAP (Ubnutu desktop -> Synology Directory Server (LDAP))
- Mount /home share
- Mount other common shares

Comment: What you're looking for is more something like consultancy than a simple question and a simple answer: break down your big problem into small problems, be specific and ask one question in ... well... one question as your question is **too broad to be answered on a Q&A site...**

Comment: @Fabby Ok i understand, but i just asked for a working and complete docs link :)

Comment: Well, luckily we have @Katu:  Docs link provided!  **:-)**